# Is there any way to lunch ChromeDriver with preserve log enabled from console settings using selenium and java?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Does ChromeDriver offer the possibility to set "Preserve log" enabled when you lunch a driver instance?
I need this because I want to keep the errors in the console during page navigation or page refresh.
[Preserve log setting screenshot from Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/24DXu.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can save the Chrome driver logs:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.logfile", your_path_to_save_file);
```